# Show that there are at most two rational points on $(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2$ for $a, b$ irrational.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

For any given irrational numbers $a, b$ and real number $r \gt 0$, show that there are at most two rational points (points whose coordinates are both rational numbers) on the circle $(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2$.

It is always suggested that askers should post their try but I literally have no idea how to approach this problem. I tried parametrization but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(a, b)$ is the center of that circle.  If there are three rational points on this circle, you can find their circumcenter by finding the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors, which can be done by solving a system of linear equations with rational coefficients, so $a$ and $b$ must also be rational.

Comment: Just one more question. How did you come up with it?

Comment: I interpreted the problem geometrically and saw that $(a, b)$ was the center, and I tried to get a contradiction assuming the opposite of what I was trying to prove.  There isn't too much you can try if all you know is that there are 3 rational points on the circle, so I tried finding the center using those three points, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Given three points $A=(x_1,y_1), B=(x_2,y_2), C=(x_3,y_3)$ all co-ordinates rational, the 3 line segments  joining them  have equations with rational coefficients and rational slope.  The midpoints P,Q,R of these 3 line segments also have rational coefficients. Now the circum centre of triangle $ABC$ is the intersection of lines passing through P, Q,R and having slopes negative reciprocal (hence rational) of slopes of AB, BC, CA.

SO the intersection point is  rational too.